# Magento 2 apply patch without upgrading Magento version

Tags: security, magento, magento2, patch, magento-2.3

I have some customers that use some "older" Magento 2 versions, like for example 2.3.4.
I would like to keep the store updated with the latest security patches but without doing a full Magento 2 upgrade.

How can I install the latest security patch (2.3.7-p1) on my 2.3.4 version?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 has a Quality Patches Tool. By using this package, you can easily install patches without having to upgrade to a new Magento version.

- Install module: `composer require magento/quality-patches`
- Check current patch status: `./vendor/bin/magento-patches status`
- Install individual patches: `./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply MAGETWO-XXXX`

Also refer to Magento documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching/mqp.html

Comment: Hi..is this tool compatible with Magento2 Open Source?

Comment: Yes, refer to: https://github.com/magento/quality-patches. It says: `Quality Patches Tool is a command-line tool that delivers quality patches for Adobe Commerce and Magento Open Source.`

Comment: Feel free to upvote / accept this answer if this is helpful.

Comment: @Armindo Pereira Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Hi...yes...i've get some errors using that tool...but i believe its from my environment

Comment: Hi Armindo. Feel free to check this answer as accepted as this seems helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manually spot all the changes between Magento 2.3.7-p1 and 2.3.7 and then based on those differences write your own patches for your Magento 2.3.4.

So basically it will be much more work then updating to 2.3.7-p1.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.